# How can I save code changes in debugging mode in vb6

Tags: vb6

When an app stops in debugging mode and I make changes to the code
Is there a way to save the code with the changes, without stop the app?

Comment: Simple answer 'No!

Comment: @JohnEason not natively, but the MZTools addin adds the feature.

Answer (score 3):

Although the VB6 IDE does not provide this natively, *an add-in for the IDE called [MZTools](https://www.mztools.com/) has been around for ages which adds this feature.*

Personally I've used MZTools 3.0 for many years, and this works really well.

This is what its help system says:

> ## Shortcut To Save File At Debug-Time
>
> The Shortcut To Save File At Debug-Time feature **allows you to define a keyboard shortcut** (Options
> window, Shortcuts tab) **to save the selected file at debug-time**. The
> Visual Basic IDE does not allow to save files at debug-time, but often
> it is useful to save the modifications that you have made to the
> source code at debug-time.
>
> ### Remarks:
>
> This feature is not available in the VBA version of MZ-Tools.  This
> feature only works at debug-time.  **Since Visual Basic disables buttons
> or menus of add-ins at debug-time, the only way to save a file at
> those times is through a keyboard shortcut.**  The file must be
> previously saved at design-time, that is, MZ-Tools does not prompt for
> a name to save the file (it shows an error message instead).

This is the options window for how I have it configured locally:

[image]

---

Note that originally MZTools was free in version 3 and later they switched to a paid version; if I hadn't gotten v3 originally however it would be well worth paying for, not only for this feature.

Comment: I've also been using MZTools since version 3 (including reporting bugs to Carlos occasionally) and I never noticed that option existed! Pity I've pretty well given up programming now!

Comment: @JohnEason too bad there was no Stack Overflow when I started programming... no way to find out these obscure things; at least now the internet is full of useful resources.

Comment: It also helps to read right through the help file! :^)

Comment: If you're still doing development in VB6, like I do, the ~ USD 80 for MZ-Tools is still worth it IMHO.

Comment: @HelO'Ween you might find https://github.com/WaynePhillipsEA/twinbasic interesting. VB6 replacement which is showing promise, though a ways to go still...

Comment: @StayOnTarget: I already had a look at it, but it doesn't cut it for our needs. We maintain a huge legacy VB6 application while it is rewritten in C#. For my personal needs, I've long switched to VB.NET. But perhaps others might find it interesting.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+S` is the shortcut I use to assign as its closest to `Ctrl+S`. Notice that the run-time save will damage forms (and user-controls) which contain user-controls from the same project group so be careful and use VCS not to cry afterwards.

Comment: @wqw that makes complete sense, I don't remember why I used +R instead. I think +S must have conflicted with something for my setup.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't.

If you make the project before the crash, maybe this piece of code can be found in a ".tmp" file. But searching in .tmps is often a waste of time.

I particularly always force myself to stop the debug and save my progress.
And I always use this setting which forces me to remember to save:

[image: Visual Basic IDE]